# Faster calculation for large amounts of data / inner loop

Tags: objective-c, macos, opencl

So, I am programming a simple Mandelbrot renderer.
My inner loop (which is executed up to ~100,000,000 times each time I draw on screen) looks like this:

```
Complex position = {re,im};
Complex z = {0.0, 0.0};

uint32_t it = 0;
for (; it < maxIterations; it++)
{
    //Square z
    double old_re = z.re;
    z.re = z.re*z.re - z.im*z.im;
    z.im = 2*old_re*z.im;

    //Add c
    z.re = z.re+position.re;
    z.im = z.im+position.im;

    //Exit condition (mod(z) > 5)
    if (sqrt(z.re*z.re + z.im*z.im) > 5.0f)
    break;
}

//Color in the pixel according to value of 'it'
```

Just some very simple calculations. This takes between 0.5 and a couple of seconds, depending on the zoom and so on, but i need it to be much faster, to enable (almost) smooth scrolling.

My question is: What is my best bet to achieve the maximum possible calculation speed?
OpenCl to use the GPU? Coding it in assembly? Dividing the image into small pieces and dispatch the calculation of each piece on another thread? A combination of those?

Any help is appreciated!

Comment: Can you think of a way to not require taking the square root?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I have written a Mandelbrot set renderer several times... and here are the things that you should keep in mind...

1. The things that take the longest are the ones that never escape and take all the iterations.

   a. so you can make a region in the middle out of a few rectangles and check that first.
2. any starting point with a real and imaginary part between -1 and 1 will never escape.
3. you can cache points (20, or 30) in a rolling buffer and if you ever see a point in the buffer that you just calculated means that you have a cycle and it will never escape.
4. You can use a more general logic that doesn't require a square root... in that if any part is less than -2 or more than 2 it will race out of control and can be considered escaped.

But you can also break this up because each point is its own thing, so you can make a separate thread or gcd dispatch or whatever for each row or quadrant... it is a very easy problem to divide up and run in parallel.

Comment: Jesus Christ, dispatching the calculation of each row asynchronously **improved the speed literally tenfold**! :O
 How would I go about caching points? Is there an easy way to determine which points will occur in a cycle without caching every single pixel?

Comment: to cache points you can either make a complex double arr[n] array, or you could translate them to a point NSPoint or your own struct. Complex gives you free equality checks and multiplication and addition...

Answer (score 4):

In addition to the comments by @Grady Player you could start just by optimising your code

```
//Add c
z.re += position.re;
z.im += position.im;

//Exit condition (mod(z) > 5)
if (z.re*z.re + z.im*z.im > 25.0f)
break;
```

The compiler may optimise the first, but the second will certainly help.

Why are you coding your own complex rather than using `complex.h`

Comment: I haven't seen much improvement with complex.h... but some... the main reason would be that it is only C99 +... or OP didn't know about it..

Comment: Indeed, removing the square root made it about 13 % faster.
I didn't use complex.h because I didn't know it existed, but since my Complex struct only consists of two doubles I don't think there will be a big improvement. I'll try it anyway.